Redis - Identify Shard Type | CLI or API
Redis Enterprise DBs come with the two following Shard Types:

Large: IOPS is 1,000 times the DB size in GB
High Throughput: IOPS is 10,000 times the DB size in GB.

The Redis DB "Export" option shows this categorization on each DB in the account/subscription. Is there a way the same can be identified using a CLI command or an API call?
